# Creating a dynamic Chrome theme

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-theme

I'm trying to build a theme extension for Google Chrome that will regularly update the background image using a remote image source (i.e. images are stored on a web server, not locally). The problem is that themes are not allowed to contain scripting elements. Any suggestions how to work around this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by background image you mean the background of the New Tab page, you can replace it with an html page (using an extension, not a theme, that is): http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html.